# ServiceNotFoundException, StartException and more on JBoss WildFly Enterprise Application project

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8, java-ee-7

iam trying to run my enterprise application project but it does not work.
WildFly cant find the index.xhtml file and giving a 404 error and it gives ServiceNotFoundException and a StartException.
The war folder has the following structure.

```
WebContent
   META-INF
   WEB-INF
      faces-config.xml
      web.xml
   index.xhtml
```

The error message is the following:

```
11:40:56,051 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."CustomerManagement.ear"."CustomerManagementEJB.jar".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."CustomerManagement.ear"."CustomerManagementEJB.jar".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of subdeployment "CustomerManagementEJB.jar" of deployment "CustomerManagement.ear"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]

Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.getRequiredService(ServiceContainerImpl.java:668) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.getDefaultResourceAdapterName(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:278)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processMessageBeans(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:155)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processAnnotations(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:82)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.processAnnotations(AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:58)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.deploy(AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:81)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
... 5 more


11:40:56,337 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.3.2.Final
11:40:56,384 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
11:40:56,387 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver (version 5.1)
11:40:56,448 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar_com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver_5_1
11:40:56,448 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1
11:40:56,453 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/VideoTrainingDS]
11:40:56,457 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/BookDS]

Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found"}}
11:40:56,608 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar" (runtime-name : "mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar")
11:40:56,610 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "CustomerManagement.ear" (runtime-name : "CustomerManagement.ear")
11:40:56,613 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.subunit."CustomerManagement.ear"."CustomerManagementEJB.jar".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."CustomerManagement.ear"."CustomerManagementEJB.jar".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of subdeployment "CustomerManagementEJB.jar" of deployment "CustomerManagement.ear"


11:40:56,647 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
11:40:56,647 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
11:40:56,648 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: WildFly 8.2.0.Final "Tweek" started (with errors) in 6202ms - Started 242 of 301 services (3 services failed or missing dependencies, 91 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
11:40:56,913 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015974: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: CustomerManagementEJB.jar) in 9ms
11:40:56,913 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015974: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: CustomerManagementWeb.war) in 9ms
11:40:56,915 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment CustomerManagement.ear (runtime-name: CustomerManagement.ear) in 11ms
11:40:57,000 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018558: Undeployed "CustomerManagement.ear" (runtime-name: "CustomerManagement.ear")
11:40:57,001 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.subunit."CustomerManagement.ear"."CustomerManagementEJB.jar".PARSE

11:41:01,689 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015003: Found CustomerManagement.ear in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called CustomerManagement.ear.dodeploy
```

Comment: Try staring Wildfly with `standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml`

Comment: you was right.it was just standalone.bat. thank you very much. you solved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try staring Wildfly with `standalone.sh/bat -c standalone-full.xml`

Comment: i have one question. i have allways to start the wildfly through command line. when i start wildfly with eclipse, the wildfly cant find the index.xhtml and it gives a http 404 error. why i have to start wildfly through the command line?